# Figure out how many deuterium atoms in a 3 microgram ice core sample

Tags: experimental-chemistry, water, hydrogen

I'm in an introductory Chemistry class and ran into a Pearson problem, that no-one in our class including our professor has been able to truly figure out.

I know the solution is $4.69 \times 10^{13}$.

Attached are images.

[image]

[image]

So far, I have tried two methods. First, I tried to calculate the answer by mass.

1) Calculate mass of deuterium

$3\times10^{-6} \times .0156 \times 10^{-2} = 4.68 \times 10^{-10}$

2) Calculate moles of deuterium

$\frac{4.68 \times 10^{-10}}{2} = 2.34 \times 10^{-10}$

3) Calculate atoms of deuterium

$2.34 \times 10^{-10} \times 6.02214 \times 10^{23} = 1.41 \times 10^{14}$

This answer is 3 times more than the actual solution.

Now, for the real B.S. that is this problem.

Let's try solving this problem by moles/atoms (as in percentage is percent deuterium by atoms)

1) Calculate moles of deuterium

$\frac{3\times10^{-6}}{18} \times 0.0156 \times 10^{-2} = 2.6 \times 10^{-11}$

2) Calculate atoms of deuterium

$2.6 \times 10^{-11} \times 6.02214 \times 10^{23} = 1.57 \times 10^{13}$

This answer is 3 times less than the real answer.

Help. What is 3?

Comment: In your second method, you missed a factor of two: you calculated the number of moles of water, but forgot that one mole of water has two moles of H atoms. So moles of deuterium is twice what you got. Then following on, the correct answer is 3.12 times 10 to the thirteenth power and the “book answer” is simply wrong. Sadly, not that uncommon.

Comment: What about the case where the molecule is HDO?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How many deuterium atoms (symbol D for deuterium) are present in $\pu {3.00 x 10^{-6} g}$ of water?

**Answer:**

$$\pu{3.00 x 10^{-6} g} \;\ \ce{H2O} \times \frac{\pu{1 mol} \;\ce{H2O}}{\pu{18.015 g} \;\ce{H2O}}\times \frac{\pu{2 mol} \;\text{H}}{\pu{1 mol} \;\ce{H2O}}\times 0.000156 \times \frac{N_\mathrm A \;\text{D atoms}}{\pu{1 mol} \;\text{D atoms}} = \pu{3.12 x 10^{13} D atoms}$$

where $N_\mathrm A = \pu{6.0221415 x 10^{23}}$ is Avogadro's number and the deuterium fractional isotopic abundance (from the wiki article on "Deuterium") is 1 deuterium atom per 6420 atomic number 1 species, i.e., 1/6420 = 0.000156 = 0.0156%. The units can be mol D per mol H.

**Alternate solution:** The probability that a water molecule is HOD, rather than HOH, is 2/6420, i.e., 1/3210 = 0.000312 = 0.0312%. This is simply due to ordinary (unsubstituted) water having two hydrogens per molecule, i.e., it is HOH, so it has two independent chances to have H replaced by D. So, *on average*, there is one HOD molecule out of every 3210 water molecules. Likewise, every 3210 moles of water contains, *on average*, 1 mole of HOD molecules.

The probability that a water molecule is DOD, rather than HOH, is the square of 1/6420, i.e., $ \pu{2.426 x 10^{-8}}$. This is negligible compared with 1/3210, so it is ignored in what follows. Therefore:

$$\pu{3.00 x 10^{-6} g} \;\ \ce{H2O} \times \frac{\pu{1 mol} \;\ce{H2O}}{\pu{18.015 g} \;\ce{H2O}}\times \frac{\pu{1 mol} \;\ce{HOD}}{\pu{3210 mol} \;\text{HOH}}\times  \frac{N_\mathrm A \;\text{D atoms}}{\pu{1 mol} \;\text{HOD}} = \pu{3.12 x 10^{13} D atoms}$$

Comment: This answer is incorrect. The correct answer is showed in the question itself. I'm going to trust my professor on this who showed that the ratio is 3 atoms in H2O to one deuterium atom

Comment: My answer is correct.

Comment: HDO actually not HDH

Comment: Please consider giving the green checkmark to the most helpful of the posted answers. It encourages people to put some thought and time into crafting answers that are factually correct, relevant, understandable and likely to be of benefit to those, in future, who encounter the question and accepted answer. It is a small reward for those who volunteer their considerable time, effort and experience to aid others and they might well look favorably at future questions from the same person. Thanks for considering this!

Answer (score -2):

I go back to your first calculations. $3.00$ microgram water does not contain $3.00$ microgram Hydrogen, as you have calculated. No ! It contains $3.00/18$ micromole of water, and also $2·3.00/18 = 0.333 $ micromole $H$. This is also $0.333$ microgram $H$. I think you can go ahead with this information. Try to calculate the mass of Deuterium in 0.333 microgram $H$.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? For example, does 0.0156% represent percentage by atoms or percentage by mass?

Comment: In the deuterium article in wiki, it says that the natural abundance of deuterium in the earth’s oceans is one deuterium per 6420 hydrogens. Then 1 divided by 6420 equals 0.000156, which is 0.0156%. Also, remember that answers in books, homeworks, exams, etc., are not always correct!

Comment: THANK YOU. This makes sense. I believe Maurice said the same thing but I struggled to understand him. My teacher gave me a similar response just now.  So the factor of 3 comes into play because H2O molecules have 3 atoms and deuterium is just 1? If you make this an answer I will accept.